# Why is binary insertion sort faster than direct insertion sort?

Tags: sorting, binary-search, insertion-sort

Implementation of direct insertion sort:

```cpp
void insertion_sort(int a[], int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int key = a[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && a[j] > key) {
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

Implementation of binary insertion sort:

```cpp
void insertion_sort(int a[], int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int key = a[i];
        int mid = upper_bound(a, a + i, key) - a;
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= mid; j--) a[j + 1] = a[j];
        a[mid] = key;
    }
}
```

Online tutorials say that binary insertion sort is faster than direct insertion sort, because binary search is faster than sequential search, but I don't think so.

Although direct insertion sort uses sequential search, when the insertion position is found, the element has already been moved. But the binary insertion sort needs to spend `O(log i)` time to find the insertion position, and the element has not been moved after finding it. If you only look at the inside of the loop, binary insertion sort takes `O(log i)` more time than direct insertion sort, so why do so many people say that the former is faster than the latter?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the overall complexity does not change since the "expensive" part is moving the elements which might be `O(n)`. Therefore the whole algorithm is still `O(n²)`. So if you look at the algorithms using asymptotic measures there's no difference between the two. If you look for the actual operation count, one can however see a difference.

Obviously, in both algorithms you have the same amount of *move* operations. What changes is the amount of comparison operations:

- With binary search you have `log(n - i)` comparison operations
- With direct insertion sort you compare within the while loop condition therefore you have as many compare operations as you have move operations (actually one more as the condition is also checked when the while loop exits), therefore you could have `n` comparison operations in a worst case scenario

Comment: The time complexity of the two algorithms is indeed the same. So you mean that binary insertion sort only has an advantage in the number of comparisons, so binary sort will be slightly faster than direct insertion sort when the number of elements is particularly large?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The difference is small. If you wanted to improve your sort performance I'd recommend to switch to an entirely different sort algorithm which has a better time complexity except you know that you have almost correctly sorted data, then insertion sort could be your best option. [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) for example also uses the idea of insertion sort for such scenarios.